# Debugging xmm registers in Assembler

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly, dll, sse

I write program in c# with assembler dll library using XMM registers.

my code in asm:

```
mov eax, 5
mov ecx, 2
movd xmm0, eax           // here 
movd xmm1, ecx           // here
addss xmm0,xmm1          // and here no difference 
movd eax, xmm0          
ret
```

It works as I want but there is a one little problem that I want to solve.
While I am debugging this code, I am changing value of eax and exc registers and it is displayed during debugging on red colore in registers window because value was changed.
But If I change value of xmm registers, it is not displayed on red color and values of this registers are still: 
XMM0 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 
XMM1 = 00000000000000000000000000000000 
and only after ret when I am in c# during debuging I can notice that registers changed.
XMM0 = 00000000000000000000000000000007 
XMM1 = 00000000000000000000000000000002
My question is: Why values of xmms do not change in register window during debugging but program works properly ?

Comment: That depends on your debugger, that you apparently forgot to mention.

Comment: You realize you're using a floating-point add, right?  You're adding two denormal floats: 7.0E-45 and 2.8E-45 to get 9.8E-45.  This happens to work, but will break as soon as you use it with integers greater than 2^23 or so, when some of the non-zero bits are in the exponent.  Perhaps your debugger is using an FP comparison with a change-threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know, the RTM update to the VS released on Dec 1st does not display the data in the debugger for YMM/XMM registers properly. The issue has been brought to the notice of MSFT team, and is being worked on.

If you can extract the SW version dated prior to Dec 1st 2015, update, that will not show this specific problem.

Hope this helps...

Comment: A further note on this - the assembler in VS 2015.1 does not generate YMM compatible code - for example, vmovdqu ymm0, mem256 will generate only XMM compatible code, and therefore, will load only 128 bits of data - MSFT has been notified and has acknowledged - this is just to prevent fellow programmers from wasting hours debugging